# Duplicate Rules

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

I have a duplicate rule that was recently created and I would like to know what would be the best process to run that rule against all the Account records in my org. The reason being I’m seeing a lot of false positives which would probably be cleaned with the new rule.

What would you guys suggest I do, given the fact that I’ve removed all the old duplicate rules.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.manage_duplicates_globally.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Yes, the salesforce edition we use isn’t performance so running the job is out of the picture. Regarding reports I tried that but it surfaced old duplicate record sets. That’s what I am wondering is what I can do to re-run these checks so at least the reports show the latest results.